# Функция не видит поля дружественного класса с++

Tags: c++, классы, дружественная-функция

```
class getpoint;
class point
{
private:
    int a;
    int b;
public:
    point(int a, int b)
    {
        this->a = a;
        this->b = b;
    }
    friend void getpoint::show(point& object);
};
class getpoint
{
public:
    void show(point& object)
    {
        cout << "A = " << object.a << endl << "B = " << object.b;
    }
};
```

В классе `getpoint` есть функция `show`, её я обьявил как дружественную для класса `point`, но почему-то в строке `cout << "A = " << object.a << endl << "B = " << object.b;` VS2019 выдаёт ошибку и пишет, что нет доступа к члену `point.a` и `point.b`.Не могу понять почему компилятор не видит их, если я обьявил функцию как дружественную для класса `point`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разместите в другом порядке:

```
class point;

class getpoint
{
public:
    void show(point& object);
};

class point
{
private:
    int a;
    int b;
public:
    point(int a, int b)
    {
        this->a = a;
        this->b = b;
    }
    friend void getpoint::show(point& object);
};


void getpoint::show(point& object)
{
    cout << "A = " << object.a << endl << "B = " << object.b;
}
```

Comment: А почему компилятор не может их видеть в моём варианте ? Хоть расположение и другое, но почему это влияет на видимость полей ?

Comment: Да хотя бы потому что когда видит описание `friend`, он не видит класса и не знает, есть ли там вообще такая функция...